# Auth0 - how can I create a multi-tier route protection system with withPageAuthRequired?

Tags: next.js, auth0

newbie here to Next.js and Auth0. We're building a web application with Next.js (using App Router) with authentication provided by Auth0. Our application needs to support multiple tiers of accounts, with each tier having access to different sets of routes in our application. For all of these routes, the user needs to be logged in.

Currently, we are using an Auth0 Login Action to determine the tier for a user account, and storing that in App Metadata and the user session (Access Token). I've been trying to find a way to extend `withPageAuthRequired` to no avail, and would like some advice from others who have done similar things.

### What I've tried

1. Dynamically setting `returnTo` for `withPageAuthRequired`.

Here is the code for how I tried dynamically setting the `returnTo` of `withPageAuthRequired` if the user tries accessing a page that they don't have access to. When I test locally, I end up at the original URL even though `returnTo` is being set to a different route.

```
import { getSession, withPageAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export const withApprovedAccountRequired = async (Component, options) => {
    const session = await getSession();
    let returnTo = '/request';
    // check the session and dynamically set returnTo
    const newOptions = {
        ...options,
        returnTo,
    };
    return withPageAuthRequired(Component, newOptions);
}
```

```
// My component
import { withApprovedAccountRequired } from "@/app/_utils/withApprovedAccountRequired"

const Protected = async () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Protected Page</h1>
            <p>This page is only accessible to logged in users.</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default await withApprovedAccountRequired(Protected, {returnTo: '/protected'});
```

2. Set `returnTo` via `withMiddlewareAuthRequired`

I implemented something similar for `withMiddlewareAuthRequired`, but this only seems to be triggered during the login action itself.

### Additional things to try

I believe I can rewrite `middleware.ts` to manually check the destination URL and trigger a redirect if necessary. However, this does not seem very extensible as the number of routes grows and the logic for determining access to routes becomes more complex.

How else can I solve my problem?